# How do I render a function which contain a view in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How do I render a function which contain a view in react native? What i get is a blank white screen

This doesnt work:

```
    class App extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <View style = { styles.container }>
                    {this._renderMapView.bind( this )}
                </View>
            );
        }

        _renderMapView () {
             return <MapView style = { styles.mapView } </MapView>
        }
   }
```

This works:

```
    class App extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <View style = { styles.container }>
                    <MapView style = { styles.mapView } </MapView>
                </View>
            );
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Not use `bind(this)`.

```
<View style = { styles.container }>
    {this._renderMapView()}
</View>
```

Or use `bind(this)` like:

```
<View style = { styles.container }>
    {this._renderMapView.bind(this)()}
</View>
```

Because you are calling a function.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because _renderMapView is not returning anything ?

```
 _renderMapView () {
          return  <MapView style = { styles.mapView } </MapView>
 }
```

Comment: i did return nothing came out too.

Answer (score 0):

try this, in the return _renderMapView missing ():

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style = { styles.container }>
                {this._renderMapView.bind( this )}
            </View>
        );
    }

    _renderMapView () {
         return (<MapView style = { styles.mapView } </MapView>);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer remove bind and add return();

Thanks everyone!

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style = { styles.container }>
                {this._renderMapView()}
            </View>
        );
    }

    _renderMapView () {
         return (
             <MapView style = { styles.mapView } </MapView>
        );
    }
 }
```